# How to check message body type in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to know message body type in swift.
Because I have the code like this `[message.body class]` by Objc.
How to do this by swift.

```
- (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController*)userContentController didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage*)message {
    NSString *name = message.name;
    NSLog(@"message name = %@",name);
    NSLog(@"body class = %@",[message.body class]);
}
```

Comment: Is type(of: message.body) what you are looking for.

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz how to write this function `type(of:)`?

Comment: you can write like: `print("type of body: \(type(of: message.body))")`

Answer (score 0):

```
guard let someString = message.body as? String else { return }
print(someString)
```